# Postgres efficiency

Tags: postgresql

Lets say that I have a table with some key, accounts, and hits.

Which is faster? I guess my question is if postgres's (or any sql for that matter) has an optimizer intelligent to see identical functions in a query

```
SELECT key, accounts, hits,1.0*hits/accounts as ratio FROM
(
    SELECT key, COUNT(DISTINCT accounts) as accounts, SUM(hits) as hits
    FROM table
    GROUP BY key
) a;
```

OR

```
SELECT key, COUNT(DISTINCT accounts) as accounts, SUM(hits) as hits, 1.0*SUM(hits)/COUNT(DISTINCT accounts) as ratio
FROM table
GROUP BY key;
```

I'd love to hear anything you have to say or resources you can provide on understanding this sort of thing. Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing the tables, indexes, and data, it's going to be really hard to say.  Have you tried EXPLAINing it?  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-explain.html

Comment: Why is an explain necessary? The question is if the optimizer is intelligent enough to realize that the COUNT(DISTINCT accounts) is identical in two places, as well as the SUM(hits), and if it will calculate each one once or twice.

Comment: If I do use Explain, however, the subquery version is marginally cheaper (819804 vs 819807)

Comment: explain tells you how the query planner will run the query.  That will tell you if it's doing something twice or only once

Comment: 819804 is not "marginally cheaper" than 819807.  That's effectively identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. That is what function volatility is for.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html

See VOLATILE vs STABLE vs IMMUTABLE.

Comment: @Leonbloy: immutable functions are called by the planner if possible; they and stable functions are then processed only once within the same statement. Calling `select stable_foo(), stable_foo(), volatile_bar(), volatile_bar();` will result in a single call to `stable_foo()` but two calls to `volatile_bar()`.

Comment: yeah, i know that, what i dont get is how that answers the question

Comment: His question is: "my question is if postgres's (...) has an optimizer intelligent to see identical functions in a query". Answer is yes, and it even spots identical functions with identical arguments. :-)

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't read well the question... 'identical functions' should rather be 'identical function calls', perhaps.